# Sort a number's digits recursively in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm very new to programming, just learned it in university. I have a task where I have to solve this problem recursively in java (without using arrays, if, else, while, etc...)

So the task is to sort numbers from 13542 to 12345.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sort(13542));

}

public static long sort(long n) {
    return n < 10
            ? n
            : sort(n, 0);
}

public static long sort(long n1, long n2) {
    return n1 > 10
            ? xxx
            : xxx;
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea what to do. I think my start is okay, but I have problems with the second method.

Comment: In translation, one 'sortiere' übersehen? s/übersehen/overlooked. The main-method doesn't mention 12345 - how should that number be introduced? Does mentioning the higher number first mean, that you have to sort them descending? All numbers between the bounds? Can you tell us, what the topics of your class have been, probably for-loops?

Comment: Start with a simpler example, which fits on the screen, for instance, like (sort 23 17). When it works, go for the serious numbers.

Comment: Generally a recursive strategy is to identify a base case, and a way to reach that base case. In the second function, you test if it is more than 10, if it is more than 10 or equal to 10, you want to split it up using integer division and modulus,
then you want to call the sort function on those n1 and n2 values. If it is less than 10 you have reached the base case and you can just return the value. At each call, you want n2 to take the largest digit from n1 and make it the smallest digit for n2.

Comment: Were you given the `long sort(long n)` method, or this is your start?

Comment: Are you required to use that method signature?  It might be simpler to treat your input as a string (or array of digits), since you'll have to deal with individual digits anyway.  Seems more confusing to keep it as an int since you're going treat it like an array.

Comment: No `if` or `else`? Oh wow. That must be a mistake. Your example code already contains a ternary conditional, though; seems the same thing to me as `if / else`.

Comment: Without an conditional (if / else) a recursive function can not terminate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, recursion means, put simply, that you have something call itself repeatedly. The fact that the assignment is on recursion is a hint of how your lecturer wants you to solve it, using a recursive method.

Ignoring the main for now, since while it could be prettied up and made more elegant, that isn't the core of the problem.

```
public int recursiveSort(int toSort){

}
```

And for neatness, we'll want a method to check if it is sorted, and to do the sorting.

```
public Boolean isSorted(int toCheck){
    //TODO: Check if input is sorted
}

public int singleSort(int toSort){
    //TODO: Sorting algorithm
}
```

Which gives us a recursive method of

```
public int recursiveSort(int toSort){
    toSort = singleSort(toSort);
    return isSorted(toSort) ? toSort : recursiveSort(toSort);
}
```

The sorting with the constraints imposed is the tricky part, and depends on exactly what you cannot use.
And of course, try to look at [different sorting algorithms](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html) and consider how you would implement them in this case.

Comment: There is a big problem with your recursion: it never progresses, as it sends *the same* parameter over and over again

Comment: I believe you meant to do `toSort = singleSort(toSort);`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure recursion with one function and one argument; without log, power, string conversion or loops. I'd say this is quite a difficult exercise in recursion even for more than a beginner. I hope this helps. Feel free to ask for any clarification. (Simplifications are also welcome.)

JavaScript code:

```js
function main() {
  console.log(sort(13542));
}

function sort(n) {
  if (n < 10)
    return n;
  
  let r = n % 10;
  let l = (n - r) / 10 % 10;

  let sorted = sort(Math.floor(n / 10) - l + r);
  let last = sorted % 10;
    
  if (l < last)
    return 10 * sort(sorted - last + l) + last;
  else 
    return 10 * sorted + l;
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

Every recursive method should include 2 main "ingredients":

1. A termination condition
2. A step forward

As you've mentioned, the obvious termination condition is that a number has only 1 digit, which means it's sorted (and therefore the recursion should stop).

The necessary progression of the method would be to remove a digit on every run, sort the smaller number and then merge the digits together.
As you can figure, the actual challenge can be either merging correctly, or separating efficiently.

I chose to locate the maximal digit, remove it from the original number and send the newly created number back into the recursive function. Eventually the method merges the sorted digits with the largest digit on their right.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sort(13542));
}

public static long sort(long n) {
    // For testing purposes:
    // System.out.println("sort(" + n + ")");

    if (n < 10) return n;   // Termination condition

    int numOfDigits = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);
    long largestDigit = n % 10;
    long restOfDigits = n / 10;

    for(int i=0; i<numOfDigits; i++) {
        long current = (long) (n / Math.pow(10, i)) % 10;
        if (current > largestDigit) {
            largestDigit = current;
            restOfDigits = (long) Math.pow(10, i) * (n / (long) Math.pow(10, i + 1))
                    + (n % (long) Math.pow(10, i));
        }
    }

    // Merge the largest number on the right
    return 10 * sort(restOfDigits) + largestDigit;
}
```

*As you can see, for testing purposes it's best to check the recursive method on its beginning. You can either print or use a debugger to see its progression.*

Comment: OP said, "without using arrays, if, else, while, etc..." that probably includes `for` as well, although I'm not sure. I think "without `if / else`" is probably a mistake, but I think I did manage to avoid loops.

Answer (score 1):

In it's simplest form, recursion is making a method call itself over and over. Here's a simple example.

```
public void eatAllFoodFromTable(Table tbl, Person prsn) {

    if(tbl.hasFood()) {

        prsn.sustain(1);
        tbl.removeFood(1);
        eatAllFoodFromTable(tbl, prsn); /*As you can see here,
            the method calls itself. However, because the method has a condition
            that can prevent it from running indefinitely (or a way to terminate),
            it will repeat until the condition is met, then terminate. This is recursion!*/

    } else {
        //Do nothing.
    }

}
```

What you want to do is take your long, and feed it into a method called `sort`, or similar. Then, that method will check to see if some of it is in order (through some kind of iteration), and then call itself (`sort()`) again with the new long generated from the sorting iteration.

Upon reaching the point where it is sorted, the method will terminate, returning the final sorted value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for your help. I think I got it now:

```
public static long sort(long n) {
    return n < 10
            ? n
            : shuffle(sort(n / (long) Math.pow(10, count(n) / 2)),
                    sort(n % (long) (Math.pow(10, count(n) / 2))));
}

public static long count(long n) {
    return n < 10
            ? 1
            : 1 + count(n / 10);
}

public static long shuffle(long n1, long n2) {
    return (n1 > 0 || n2 > 0)
            ? (n1 % 10 > n2 % 10)
                    ? shuffle(n1 / 10, n2) * 10 + n1 % 10
                    : shuffle(n1, n2 / 10) * 10 + n2 % 10
            : 0;
}
```

Sadly we weren't allowed to use if, else or while. This would have been so much easier. But thank you all :)